# Do we need to persist redux store data while creating mobile apps with react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

While creating apps with reactJS we need to persist the redux state data, because the store gets reinitialized when the **browser is refreshed**. Is this scenario applicable while creating mobile apps? I mean the mobile apps cannot be refreshed right?

So, while creating mobile apps with react native we need not have to bother about persisting the data fearing that the app will be refreshed? Please correct me if I'am wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like on desktop applications, your application can be closed, the device can restart, etc, and everything not persisted goes away.

You should store anything you don't want to lose in [AsyncStorage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html) or similar.

Answer (score 0):

React-Native Redux can only persists data till application has terminated. You need to store require data in Asynchronous storage or can pull data from your server using APIs.